# Integrate perl documentation in Perl5 plugin for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, ide

I am using Perl5 plugin ([Camelcade](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7796)) for IntelliJ IDEA, how can I integrate perldoc in it?

Comment: Which plugin? Camelcade?

Comment: @choroba : yes Camelcade

Answer (score 0):

You can't for now. But you may post a feature request on the github.